# Getting beautifulsoup to work in an Azure webjob

Tags: python, azure, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, azure-web-app-service

I have a script working in Python using BeautifulSoup to scrape data.

I am now trying to get this working in an Azure webjob, the script runs fine locally, but despite having all the relevant libraries etc installed on the Azure instance, I am getting the following errors:

```
[07/15/2017 10:34:19 > 549cdd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[07/15/2017 10:34:19 > 549cdd: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[07/15/2017 10:34:19 > 549cdd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[07/15/2017 10:34:19 > 549cdd: INFO] 
[07/15/2017 10:34:19 > 549cdd: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\AzureStats\cc5r5rjy.yjd>D:\home\python361x64\python.exe get_stats.py 
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "get_stats.py", line 12, in <module>
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     html = requests.get('%smatches.asp' % URL)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     return request('get', url, **kwargs)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 354, in request
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 460, in send
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 211, in send
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     timeout=timeout
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in urlopen
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 231, in _get_conn
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     return conn or self._new_conn()
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python361x64\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 198, in _new_conn
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ]     strict=self.strict)
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: ERR ] TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[07/15/2017 10:34:22 > 549cdd: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

I am guessing its something fairly basic as its all running locally fine, does anyone have any experience running a beautifulsoup script on python that can help with the above ?

Cheers

Comment: Is that an HTTP or HTTPS URL?

Comment: Do you use the most recent version of the `requests` lib?

Comment: Yeah it was the requests version :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on Python 3, you need requests to be at least 2.7.0.

Can you please verify what version of requests are you running?

Comment: @PeteStilgoe glad I could help!